# Number theory: 2 numbers within a set with same difference

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

You have the numbers 1,2,3...,99,100. From that set you have to choose 55 different numbers.

Show that:

> > There are 2 numbers with a difference 9,10,12,13
> >
> > Show that there aren't neccessarily 2 with a difference 11.

I have no idea how to do this, it seems really counterituitive to me. How do i approach this?

Reworded to be correct:
Prove that however one selects 55 integers 1 ≤ x1 < x2 < x3 < ... < x55 ≤ 100, there will be some two that differ by 9, some two that differ by 10, a pair that differ by 12, and a pair that differ by 13. Surprisingly, there need not be a pair of numbers that differ by 11.

Comment: For 1) I would try using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: If you choose 1, 12, and 53 others there are two with a difference of 11. Or do I miss something obvious?

Comment: I don't get this.

Comment: Am I missing something or is there some additional restriction? If I pick {1, 2, ..., 55} then I have lots of pairs with difference 11?

Comment: @M.B. I'll reword

Comment: @CompuChip I reworded

Comment: @ulead86 it's mostly the 11 one that is eluding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by choosing numbers from your set of numbers and think yout the pigeonhole principle:

- For differing by $9$, we would arrange $9$ consecutive numbers $1$ to $9$, but then need a gap of 9, so the next would be $19-27$, continuing with $37-45$, $55-63$, $73-81$, $91-99$. This uses $54$ numbers, with no place for the 55th except in some hole less that is than $9$ from some other entry. Only by choosing $100$ will it differ from only one other number. All other choices will differ by $9$ from two numbers.
- For $10$, we have $1-10$, $21-30$, $41-50$, $61-70$, $81-90$ which leaves $5$ numbers and all remaining holes ten away from an existing number.
- For $11$, we have $1-11$, $23-33$, $45-55$, $67-77$, and $89-100$, which uses all $55$ numbers.
- Twelve can have $1-12$, $25-36$, $49-60$, $73-84$, $97-100$, which accounts for $52$ of the $55$.
- Thirteen can have $1 -13$, $27-39$, $53-65$, $79-91$,which accounts for $52$ of the numbers. Note that once we can have $\lfloor55/4 \rfloor$= 14 numbers in a group there is no
  problem, e.g. $1 -14$, $29-42$, $57-71$, $86-99$ allows for $56$ numbers.

Comment: Yes, but the 11 case is what eludes me

Comment: @Phaptitide: Edit

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: copied straight from another website, https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS5umoidrOAhXkbZoKHa-hB4UQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcsiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu%2F~ssdavis%2F20%2FChapter%25205%2C%2520Techniques%2520of%2520Counting.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGaM9ijCYLzBf-Za-ZSVxgcOa8b6A
why not just link it?

Comment: @gebra, link-only answers are generally frowned upon.  But a verbatim source really should be acknowledged.  On the other hand, are you sure the site you linked to existed three years ago?  (My guess is it did, since the incorrect floor function in $\lfloor55/4\rfloor=14$ here appears as a correct ceiling function there.  Note, though, that *both* answers give $89-100$ as the final stretch of numbers for $11$ instead of the correct $89-99$.)

Comment: Alright, i guess it makes things clearer to write it up

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the condition for a gap of size $n$ to have to occur between values is $n\cdot{[\frac{x}{2n}]}<p$ where $p$ is the number of values between 1 and $x$ inclusive, and $[z]$ is defined as the round to the nearest integer function.

EDIT this test only guarantees the correct answer if the absolute value of $|\frac{p}{n}-\frac{x}{2}|>\frac{1}{2}$. Otherwise, the correct equation is changed when the fractional part of $\frac{x}{2n}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$. It just becomes $x <2p$.

Comment: Do you round up or down when $z$ is a half integer?

Comment: You round up, not down